# (Python) Can 'array' be a variable name?

Tags: python, numpy, variables, naming-conventions

In the following example 1:

<example 1>

```
 import numpy as np

 np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
```

Is array after np. a method function?  If so, can array be used as a variable name?  Please check the the following example 2?

<example 2>

```
 import numpy as np

 array = np.arange(5)

 print(array)
```

Are 'array' in example 1 and example 2 different or same?

Comment: If you've shadowed the function, you won't be able to use it again to make another array. Try assigning `array`, and then using `np.array` again afterwards to see what happens (although, in case 2 you are using `np.arange` not `np.array`).

Comment: The first case its (np.array) a function and in the 2nd case its (array) a variable and both are different. You can use the function name as variable but that is not recommended.

Comment: @Kraigolas nothing will happen, `array = np.array([1,2,3])` doesn't shadow anthing

Comment: They are obviously different. did you try `print(array)` and `print(np.array)`?

Comment: @NilanjanDasKhan there is absolutely no problem with using the name `array`. It is a perfectly reasonable name, albeit, not a very descriptive one.

Comment: I often use `arr` as a variable name.  Think of it as stylized form of 'array'. As long as you don't shadow something important, the main question is - is it clear to you and your users?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Agreed! My comment was to suggest that OP could (and should) test this behaviour for themselves to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this line to see which keywords are not allowed in python:

```
help("keywords")
```

As you can see array is not one of them, so you can use it as a variable name.

However array in `np.array()` is the method name (there is a dot before it, which it means it is part of numpy library). So in your example 2 "array"s are different.

Comment: It's not just keywords you need to worry about, it's also built-in functions like `print()`. You _can_ use those as names, but it's not a good idea.